# Passing condition to a var in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I don't know how to solve this. I need something like this:

```
var condition;
if (a==1) //a comes from another part
    condition = "arr3[cliente].año == year";
if (a==2)
    condition = "arr3[cliente].año == year && arr3[cliente].sic"

//now another if

if (condition){
      //rest of code
}
```

I need different conditions depending some previous values, the code inside the last if is always the same, so I don't need:

```
if (arr3[cliente].año == year)
    // code
else if (arr3[cliente].año == year && arr3[cliente].sic)
    // code
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign the result of the expressions to the variable (currently you are assigning a *string*). The expression doesn't have to be inside the `if` statement, the **result** is what's important:

```
var condition;
if (a==1)
    condition = arr3[cliente].año == year;
if (a==2)
    condition = arr3[cliente].año == year && arr3[cliente].sic;

// It this point `condition` will either have the value `undefined`, `true` or `false`.    
if (condition) {
  // code
}
```

---

Of course you can simplify/reduce this to the following:

```
if (arr3[cliente].año == year && (a == 1 || a == 2 && arr3[cliente].sic)) {
  // code
}
```

No need for repeating `if` statements or comparisons. This also assumes that accessing any of the properties doesn't have any side effects.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll take this answer because was the first one.

Comment: (@pmirnd) For readability, I might put the condition in parentheses, `condition = (...)`, so a careless glance doesn't see only `condition = arr3[cliente].año`. It's not a grammatical concern (this answer works perfectly as-is), but I think parens help readability. (Take or leave this advice as you please!)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the conditions you have, but not as strings. They'll either be true or false and your `if(condition)` check will still work fine.

```
var condition;
if (a == 1) //a comes from another part
    condition = arr3[cliente].año == year;
if (a == 2)
    condition = arr3[cliente].año == year && arr3[cliente].sic;

//now another if

if (condition) {
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll take the other answer because was first. I'll put +1 to this one though.

Answer (score 1):

My proposition. if a==1 you will need the rest of condition and if a==2 you'll need second option condition.

```
if (a==1 && (arr3[cliente].año == year)){
    commonFunction();
} else if (a==2 && (arr3[cliente].año == year && arr3[cliente].sic)){
    commonFunction();
}

function commonFunction() {
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use this, I have a problem with "cliente" in arr3, because it's defined inside a "for (cliente in arr3)" so this one will works better, but the question was better answered by the first one. Thanks.